# Git and Mercurial: what would be equivalent of Git workflow in Mercurial?

Tags: git, mercurial

```
#lets get the latest
git pull

#lets switch to branch and do some work
git checkout -b makeSomeBugs

#do the work commit
git add .
git commit -am "introducing some bugs"

#push this for my lazy remote friend to see
git push origin makeSomeBugs

#uh .. changes on master
git pull origin master

#do some work..
git commit -am "introducing some more bugs"
git push origin makeSomeBugs

#lets switch back to master
git checkout master
git pull

#work is done, lets merge
git merge --no-ff makeSomeBugs
git push origin

#and remove the branch to never ever see it again
git push origin :makeSomeBugs
git branch -d makeSomeBugs
```

Various blog sources (but they are quite old) say that branching like this in mercurial is no-go, especially with permanent branch removal...

Comment: I have tried and yet to find a way to simulate a git branch workflow in mercurial.  Regular branch diffidently don't work because you can't delete them (only close them but that means that branch name is taken forever).  Bookmarks are supposed to be like git branches however they don't seems to really work like them, at least to me.

Comment: @ryanzec how did bookmarks fail you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I might have some bits wrong because I may have misunderstood the git, but assuming you're using a recent version of Mercurial or if not, the [bookmarks extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Bookmarks) is enabled...

```
# lets get the latest
# git pull

hg pull

# lets switch to branch and do some work
# git checkout -b makeSomeBugs

hg bookmark makeSomeBugs

# do the work commit
# git add .
# git commit -am "introducing some bugs"

hg commit -m "introducing some bugs"

# push this for my lazy remote friend to see
# git push origin makeSomeBugs

hg push -B makeSomeBugs

# uh .. changes on master
# git pull origin master

hg pull
hg merge

# do some work..
# git commit -am "introducing some more bugs"
# git push origin makeSomeBugs

hg commit -m "introducing some more bugs"
hg push -B makeSomeBugs

# lets switch back to master
# git checkout master
# git pull

hg pull
hg update -C <name of master rev>

# work is done, lets merge
# git merge --no-ff makeSomeBugs
# git push origin

hg merge makeSomeBugs
hg push

# and remove the branch to never ever see it again
# (I assume you mean the label not the changesets)
# git push origin :makeSomeBugs
# git branch -d makeSomeBugs

hg bookmark -d makeSomeBugs
hg push -B makeSomeBugs
```

There's a couple of "mental model" differences, but I think it's pretty close. Biggest one is when you delete the bookmark. You delete it locally and then push that it's deleted. Reversed order from what you did with git.

There's also the question of what you use to identify the "master" head. If there was a bookmark already on the server for it (called `master` for example) the first line would become `hg pull -B master`, the first merge `hg merge master` and the update `hg update -C master`. Once you've pulled a bookmark the first time any subsequent pulls or pushes should update it without needing to explicitly mention it.

Comment: So the question is, can see in history that changes made in makeSomeBugs when they are merged to default and pushed to origin are still visible as changes in makeSomeBugs ? E.g. can i track that comit X and commit Y were made in makeSomeBugs after merging?

Comment: @gerasalus: No, just like Git branches, bookmarks are not permanent. Named branches are permanent labels, and they have no Git equivalent. `default` refers to the default *named* branch. It is not the same as `master`.

Comment: @PaulS: You don’t need to enable the bookmarks extension anymore nowadays because it became a core Mercurial feature now.

Answer (score 5):

It’s pretty much the same except that with Mercurial you generally wouldn’t bother naming your progress at all and just use an anonymous branch.

I’ll let that sink in for a moment...

Unlike git, Mercurial doesn’t ‘forget’ changesets if there is no branch name or bookmark associated with it, so there is no need for naming it, and subsequently deleting it. After this, it looks like a pretty standard workflow:

```
#lets get the latest
hg pull

#lets update to the latest and do some work
hg update

#do the work commit
hg commit -Am "introducing some bugs"

#serve this for my lazy remote friend to see
hg serve

#uh .. remote changes
hg pull

#do some work..
hg commit -Am "introducing some more bugs"

#lets pull in the latest
hg pull

#work is done, lets merge
hg merge
hg push
```

Optionally you can use a bookmark if you really want to explicitly keep track of the anonymous head; when you start (after `hg update`), label the current changeset using:

```
hg bookmark makeSomeBugs
```

And when you’re done (after `hg merge`), remove the bookmark using:

```
hg bookmark -d makeSomeBugs
```

You could also push the bookmark for your friend’s sake, but... meh.

Comment: You are commiting to the default, i'm commiting to the branch. This is not the same. As i can create another branch from master and do any other stuff, non related to the first one.

Comment: No, you’re committing to a new, anonymous branch, optionally with a bookmark. Branching happens whenever the line of commits diverges. If you want to commit under something else than the `default` name, then you need to make another *named* branch. You’re hitting a cultural snag here: using anonymous branches is common in Mercurial, while it is pretty much impossible in Git. Named branches are permanent and need to be set in advance; if you want to track that anonymous branch, you use a bookmark.

Comment: In Mercurial, named branches are permanent and typically used to track releases. You can use them to track features too, but usually feature work is done in anonymous branches. Bookmarks can optionally be used to track work on anonymous branches. This is useful if you are working on multiple things at once or the code needs to be shared before merging it back.

Comment: Named branches are nice for tracking releases because then in the project history you can see what release changesets were for. However for feature work they are often inconvenient, e.g. because you can’t be bothered to come up with a branch name, or you’ve already made a few commits before you realising that you want to label them, or (like in your question) you don’t want the label to persist. So that is why features are usually done on anonymous branches, sprinkled with some bookmarks (or separate clones) as needed.

Comment: Ok it seems that i'm hiting a big cultural snag. If you have not used any bookmarks, and have issued a commit for Bug X how can you start working on Bug Y but exclude thet commit from Bug X ? I think this is possible only if i use bookmarks (considering that i do not use named branches for their permanent nature)

Comment: @gerasalus So in git I'd guess you'd `checkout master` right? What you're doing is moving back to the revision before the commit to fix bug X. You do the same thing in mercurial. We'd `hg update <revision>` where revision might be a tag, bookmark, branch-name, or just a plain revision number. What ever gets you back to where you want to be. I think the cultural thing is that in Mercurial we're quite used to moving around the DAG. In git you're moving between "branches" which moves you around the DAG.

Comment: @gerasalus: Actually no, you don’t need bookmarks at all! Up until version 1.8 they weren’t even part of core Mercurial. Say you are on revision 1 and commit a fix for bug X as changeset 2, then `hg update 1` back to revision 1 and commit a fix for bug Y as changeset 3. Now you have two branches, and you can decide to only push the fix for bug X using `hg push -r 2`. Bookmarks are only optional labels which may help you track where you left your changes.

Comment: Paul has a good point about the DAG there. I guess you could say that in Mercurial you generally operate on a lower level than in Git, which has built a big branching model on top of the DAG (even with branch namespaces and all that). I think that is a reason why people say Mercurial is simpler, but if you’re used to Git I can see how it may be confusing.

Comment: LaurensHolst, PaulS thank you both. You helped a lot. @PaulS using bookmarks seems more close to git branching, so i'll accept his answer

Comment: I think that's the first time I've had a zero rated answer accepted ;-) Glad it all helped.